# Windows Server 2012 NIC Teaming

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I recently upgraded our file server with two NIC's and configured NIC teaming. I tested the file transfer and noticed that the file transfer only happen one at a time. Example: I have a 1GB file that I started downloading on two different machines at the same time. The first one started downloading and the second on paused until the first one was complete.

I thought the purpose of the NIC teaming was to have more bandwidth through load balancing? Did I miss something during configuration? I enabled multiply transfers through powershell but still one transfer at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of NIC teaming that you're doing. Did you configure this by Server 2012 R2's [built in NIC teaming facilities](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/10/16/nic-teaming-in-windows-server-2012-do-i-need-to-configure-my-switch.aspx), or by using vendor-specific driver teaming?

[From here](https://serverfault.com/a/569723/7709):

> LACP will not split packets across multiple interfaces for a single stream/thread. For example a single TCP stream will always send/receive packets on the same NIC.

The same also applies to Etherchannel. Did you also configure your switches if you're using LACP?

If you've just configured them in active/standby then only one NIC will ever actually be used.

But the activity that you've described is very odd. The second one should *not* pause. Typically both transfers will take place, with the bandwidth split roughly 50/50 between the two. What protocol did you use to do the test?

Comment: It was a simple file transfer over a windows share.